# VueJS js how to show dynamic form

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vue.I have a vue which needs to receive and show different template models.

I've tried this (simulating dynamic injection of one input field):

```
<template>
  <b-container v-if="show">
    <b-row>
      <b-col class="map-dialog" cols="12" sm="6" md="4" >
        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
        <component v-bind:is="fields"></component>
        <b-button v-on:click="hide">Close</b-button>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {
  props: {
    show: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: null,
      fields: null,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fields = Vue.component('fields', {
        template: '<b-form-input v-model="text1" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name"></b-form-input>'
      })
  },
}
```

This gives an error:

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template 
compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render
functions, or use the compiler-included build.
```

What to do?

Comment: did you try to register that component globally like : `Vue.component(....) export default{...}`?

Comment: No, I don't want it to be registered globally. The component will vary depending on table, user, etc. so needs to be fetched from the server, or created from a template on the server.

Comment: i think you're looking for something like  [`async components`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components)

Comment: `:is` take as value the name of the component not the component itself

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from @Boussadjra Brahim, I found a solution using [async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components).

Here is the amended code:

```
<template>
  <b-container v-if="show">
    <b-row>
      <b-col class="map-dialog" cols="12" sm="6" md="4" >
        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
        <FormFields/>
        <b-button v-on:click="hide">Close</b-button>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
export default {
  props: {
    show: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: null,
      fields: null,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    Vue.component('FeatureFields', function (resolve, reject) {
      resolve({
        template: '<b-form-input  type="text" placeholder="Enter your name"></b-form-input>'
      })
    });
  },
}
```

I also needed to change `import Vue from 'vue'` to import Vue from `'vue/dist/vue.js` so that it would compile the template.